# No wireless after ugrade from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

Finally upgraded to 12.04 LTS on a Dell 630 Latitude and the wireless stopped working after reboot.

Have tried to install STA, b43 even NDISwrapper in various ways due to crappy slow internet and it's still not working. I'm not very techy but I have installed a few ubuntu systems and got the wireless working in the past I know it's got to be something simple I just cant see it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$ lspci 
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 0c) 
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c) 
    00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 0c) 
    00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02) 
    00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02) 
    00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller  #2 (rev 02) 
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02) 
    00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02) 
    00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02) 
    00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 02) 
    00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller   #1 (rev 02) 
    00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02) 
    00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02) 
    00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02) 
    00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f2) 
    00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02) 
    00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 02) 
    00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02) 
    00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02) 
    03:01.0 CardBus bridge: O2 Micro, Inc. Cardbus bridge (rev 21) 
    03:01.4 FireWire (IEEE 1394): O2 Micro, Inc. Firewire (IEEE 1394) (rev 02) 
    09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02) 
    0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
```

```
$ iw config 
nl80211 not found.
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
          *-network UNCLAIMED     
           description: Network controller
           product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
           vendor: Broadcom Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
           version: 01
           width: 32 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1c:23:03:15:c3
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.121 duplex=full firmware=5755m-v3.29 ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 memory:fe7f0000-fe7fffff
```

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep Network
    0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest, with a temporary working internet connection:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe b43
```

Detach the temporary connection and let us hear your results.